# Find a matrix/vector such that AB = A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The title pretty much states the question. I was wondering if there was a general solution, theorem or concept that easily solves my question for the general case. Given a non-zero matrix B, how can we find a non-zero vector/matrix A such that A = AB? Thanks!

Comment: Take the zero vector or zero matrix

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that helps here.

Comment: Any matrix multiplied by the zero vector will give the zero vector. Similarly, any matrix multiplied by the zero matrix again yields the zero matrix. Hence $AB=A$ if $A$ is the zero vector/matrix and $B$ is any matrix.

Comment: Ahh I see, I should edit the question to indicate I mean non-zero matrixes/vectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim:** An $A \neq 0$ exists if and only if $1$ is an eigenvalue for $B$.
In this case all the rows of $A$ must be either 0 or eigenvectors for $B^T$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.

**Sketch of Proof**
Note first that $B$ must be square since otherwise $AB$ and $A$ have different sizes.

Then
$$AB=A \Leftrightarrow A(B-I)=0$$

Now, if $1$ is not an eigenvalue for $B$ then $B-I$ is invertible and hence $A=0$.

Therefore $1$ must be an eigenvalue for $B$ and hence $B^T$. In this case
$$ A(B-I)=0\Leftrightarrow (B^T-I)A^T=0$$
which is equivalent to
$$(B^T-I)c_i =0$$
for every column $c_i$ of $A$. This is equivalent to
$$B^Tc_i =c_i$$
for every column $c_i$ of $A^T$ (meaning row of $A$).

The claim follows.

Comment: Thank you, this is super clear! I haven't learned about eigenvalues yet so I wasn't able to figure it out on my own.